# Bootstrap4 datetime picker: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I've encountered an error on my date picker using the bootstrap4. I've read all about the error online and the only solution keeps coming is the one about the arrangement of calling 's. I did the same I called Jquery first above all 's but the error still persist.
Below is my code for HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing/Experiment</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/MDBv4.16.0/css/mdb.min.css">

    <script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"
        integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"
        integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <img src="rsc/mblogo.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/">CAM DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--End of nav.sidebar-->
        </nav>

        <!--Page content-->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container content-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <input placeholder="Selected date" type="text" id="date-picker-example"
                        class="form-control datepicker">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                            <h5 class="card-header">
                                Bar Chart
                            </h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="bar-chart">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of div.row-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <h5 class="card-header">
                                Top 5 Reason for downtime
                            </h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <ul id="top5Downtime">

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <h5 class="card-header">
                                Pie Chart
                            </h5>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="pieChart">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of div.row-->
            </div>


        </div>
        <!--End of div.content-->

    </div>
    <!--End of div.wrapper-->
    <script src = "js/datePicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pieChart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sidebarScript.js"></script>

    <script src = "src/MDBv4.16.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my datePicker.js:

// Data Picker Initialization

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        showMonthsShort: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `pickdate`, Its `datepicker` and here order matters, so be careful.

### ORDER

I like this order in `CSS` and `JS` and it not creates problem in long time

**CSS**

1. Bootstrap
2. MD Bootstrap
3. Font-Awesome
4. Your CSS File

**JS**

> Put your all scripts before `body (</body)` tag closing.

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap
3. MD Bootstrap
4. Font-Awesome
5. D3.JS
6. Charts JS
7. Datepicker
8. Your JS File

```html
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/MDBv4.16.0/css/mdb.min.css"> -->

<!-- <script src="src/jquery.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="src/d3.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js"
integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<!-- <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js"
integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <img src="rsc/mblogo.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">CAM DASHBOARD</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--End of nav.sidebar-->
    </nav>

    <!--Page content-->
    <div id="content">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container content-header">
            <div class="row">
                <input placeholder="Selected date" type="text" id="date-picker-example"
                class="form-control datepicker">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Bar Chart
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="bar-chart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Top 5 Reason for downtime
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul id="top5Downtime">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <h5 class="card-header">
                            Pie Chart
                        </h5>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="pieChart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of div.content-->
</div>

<!--End of div.wrapper-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src = "js/datePicker.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="js/script.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="js/pieChart.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="js/sidebarScript.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src = "src/MDBv4.16.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script> -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            weekdaysShort: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            showMonthsShort: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! after arranging it as you said. The same error still persist.